# Problem with multiple event handling in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I have a strange jQuery problem with multiple event handlers. What I'm trying to achieve is this:

1. User selects some text on the page
2. If the selection is not empty - show a context menu
3. If user clicks somewhere else - the context menu should disappear

I'm having troubles with the above i.e. sometimes the context menu appears correctly, sometimes it appears and disappears straight after user makes a selection. Please help. See the relevant parts of my code below. Also when user selects a paragraph or a word by double clicking - context menu appears and quickly disappears again.

```
var ContextMenu = {
   ...
        show: function(e) {
            var z = this;
            if (!this.shown) {
                if (this.contextMenu) {
                    this.contextMenu.css({
                        left: e.pageX,
                        top: e.pageY
                    }).slideDown('fast');
                    this.shown = true;
                }
                var hideHandler = function() {
                    z.hide(this);
                };
                $(document.body).bind("click", hideHandler);
            }
        },
        hide: function(hideHandler) {
            if (this.contextMenu && this.shown) {
                this.contextMenu.slideUp('fast');
                this.shown = false;
                $(document.body).unbind("click", hideHandler);

            }
        }
};
    // Context menu display logic
    $(document.body).bind("mousedown mouseup", function(e) {
        if ((window.getSelection().toString() != "") && (!ContextMenu.shown)) {
            ContextMenu.show(e);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

See if binding the event only to `mouseup` helps:

```
$(document.body).bind("mouseup", function(e) {
     if ((window.getSelection().toString() != "") && (!ContextMenu.shown)) {
         ContextMenu.show(e);
     }
 });
```

From what I unserstand you don't need to bind it to the `mousedown` event.

I think, if you bind it to the `mousedown` event and the user makes a selection by dragging the mouse (and pressing the button), your context menu is shown (`mousedown`) and the **`click` handler is bound to the document while the mouse button is still pressed**. Thus, after releasing the mouse button (as of finishing the selection), **a `click` is performed** and the previously bound `click` handler **gets executed**, making the menu disappear again.

I could be wrong though ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Felix, unfortunately that didn't solve it :( After changing to 'mouseup' - my context menu appears and immediately disappears 100% of times. Don't know what to do about it.

Comment: @Felix - I'd try a `setTimeout()` on binding the hide click handler ;)

Comment: Following Nick Craver's advice I tried changing this line:

    $(document.body).bind("click", hideHandler);

to:

    setTimeout(function() {
       $(document.body).bind("click", hideHandler);
    }, 2000);

It works only once - and the context menu exhibits correct behavior. However, after that things roll back to "appear/disappear immediately".

Any other thoughts?

I kinda added a 'close' button to my context menu and it works fine, though it is not very elegant.